# Is there a way to rotate UV islands to face the same direction based on their position in the 3D space?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a building with many windows, that have cubemapped interiors. A lot of the UVs for the windows are facing the wrong way so as a result the rooms are upside down.

To fix this i would like to rotate all of the window UV islands so that the top of the uv and the top of the window are alligned in the same direction in the viewport.

Is this possible? There are hundreds of windows, I'd really like to not have to go though all of them.

[image: Screen shot from Blender showcasing the issue]